# What do I change my socket to?

Tags: java, sockets, web, client

alI created a simple text based RPG and after alot of work managed to put it on a website (www.worldofthedrakon.com). I just created a server and client but I am having problems with users accessing the server from their computer. I have my socket set up as:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8800);
```

Now i have tested changing localhost out for my IP, to no avail. The errors I'm getting are connection timed out, and connection refused. Could someone point me in the right direction? I apologize if my problem seems vague, more code can be provided. Theres alot of it so I didnt want to bombard you :) Thank you.
ServerSide:

```
public Server() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(jta), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setTitle("Multi-Thread Server");
        setSize(500, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8800);
            jta.append("MultiThreadServer started at " + new Date() + '\n');

            int clientNo = 1;

            while(true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                jta.append("Server Thread for client " + clientNo + " at " + new Date() + '\n');

                InetAddress inetAdress = socket.getInetAddress();
                jta.append("Client " + clientNo + "'s host name is " + inetAdress.getHostName() + "\n");
                jta.append("Client " + clientNo + "'s IP Address is " + inetAdress.getHostAddress() + "\n");

                HandleAClient task = new HandleAClient(socket);

                new Thread(task).start();

                clientNo++;
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
```

Client Side:

```
try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8800);

            fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            jta_TextArea.setText(ex.toString() + '\n');
        }
```

Comment: What are you using for your server? ServerSocket? or a webserver?

Comment: provide the code related to net connection including server-side code and client-side code.@Benjamin Braga

Comment: ServerSocket,  code provided @Bloodwolf

Comment: Socket socket = new Socket("lockhost", 8800); the string "lockhost" is an invalid host name. use "localhost" instead, or it's just a clerical error.@Benjamin Braga

Comment: Oh snap, no lockhost was supposed to be local host, I had changed it from my IP when inserting on this page. it was not originally lockhost haha @Bloodwolf

Comment: has the problem been fixed? @Benjamin Braga

Answer (score 2):

Your socket is bound to `localhost` this means in can only serve the local client. If you want others to see your server the first step is to bind to the IP address that is visible to those others!

Comment: I was thinking that too, but if he is using ServerSocket, thats probably not the case. If he used ServerSocket he probably used the ctor and bound to a port, which then wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Yes I am using ServerSocket, do you know where I need to go from here?

Comment: Well I am trying to store user information on the server I built above, but all i created was a way for me to save just my information. Any other computer just gets denied. How can I set it so user variables get sent to the server and can be loaded from their upon request? Am I on the right track up above? Or am I asking the wrong this from Java? I've put so much time and effort into this game Im hoping I can get a trace of what I need to do next

Comment: You are on the right track, although I think you can benefit a lot if you read more about client/server programming and sockets. Also you may want to do all of this using a webserver and REST api. That might be the best way to go.

Comment: Thank you Ali, I just bought a giant book on Networking but now that I have some things I can do research with ill get right on it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to be using a [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and not a regular socket.

Comment: That was clientside the ServerSocket is in the Server I believe.

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" is exactly that; it is your local host or your machine.  If you are trying to connect your socket to some other host (like whatever resolves to www.worldofthedrakon.com), you need to get that hostname or its IP address in there.

```
Socket socket = new Socket("worldofthedrakon.com", 8800);
```

Then you get to fight the firewall issues.  Connection Refused is usually an indication that there is a firewall or two in the way.  Do you know that port 8800 is open on your new host?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I tried to temporarily turn off the firewalls upon testing it on both computers to no avail. The website it is on is hosted by a company, So Im assuming I cant use that hostname? Is there no way to have my client connect to a server thats on my computer? @Bob Kuhar

Comment: To the best of my knowledge (I lack network expertise), if both of your machines are on the same network (IP address from the same DHCP server), you should be able to do this with just the IP address of the machine on which your server is running.  For example, on my home network, my machine is 10.0.1.7 and my wife's machine is 10.0.1.4.  If the ServerSocket is listening on my wife's machine, I would construct the client Socket( "10.0.1.4", 8800 ).  I have no idea how someone outside of my network would connect to her machine by IP address or otherwise (I think this is where DNS comes in).

Comment: When you say the IP address of the machine would you be referring to the internal or External, I would guess external right? DNS hmmm, I guess Ill head to Barnes and Nobles and see if they have any books on this subject. I understand what Im asking and what Im doing is two different things now. But unfortunately none of the 3 giant java books I have cover writing to a server from other computers. Which is a shame. Thank you again for your response :)